# Причастный оборот между неоднородными определениями

Tags: пунктуация

Тем не менее, при более пристальном рассмотрении системы можно обнаружить некоторые (,) оказывающие влияние (,) важные факторы.

Нужны ли в данном предложении запятые, выделяющие прич. оборот, по аналогии с *среди густых, в сумерках потемневших, развесистых елок*? Или здесь первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения с существительным, как *заячий наполовину потёртый воротник; большой собранный автором материал* и т. п.?

Также и здесь: Техника во многих случаях требует линейного движения, и поэтому короткоходовые силогенерирующие цилиндры находят не меньшее применение, чем длинноходовые (,) навиваемые на барабаны канаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом предложении определение "некоторые" относятся не к причастному обороту, а к словосочетанию "важные факторы". Запятая нужна. ***Ср.: Некоторые важные факторы, оказывающие влияние.***

Во втором предложении запятая тоже нужна,т.к причастный оборот стоит после определения-прилагательного и перед определяемым словом.

См.Академический справочник. § 38.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я тоже думала о том, что если переместить оборот, то запятая будет нужна.